# PHP: get int from date diff

Tags: php, date

I'm using this to get the number of days between two dates:

```
$nbDays = $dateArrival->diff($dateDeparture);
```

I can use "->format()" if I want to output this to the screen. But how can I transform this into an INT if I want to use the number of days in a multiplication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) returns a [`DateInterval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.days) which has a public *days* property.

```
$nbDays = $dateArrival->diff($dateDeparture);
echo $nbDays->days;
```

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `DateTime::diff` is a [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.days). If you look at the documentation, you will see that class has a `days` field which you can use to get an integer number of days.